# Retrofit -> Log to file

Tags: android, logging, retrofit

I'm using a custom logger to log both to `Logcat` and to file (when the file is enabled).

This really helps when receiving bug reports from testers (because I have also a button inside the app to send a bug report with the logs attached).

The problem: I'm using `RetroFit`, but I haven't **how I can intercept it's logs and send them also to file** if possible, with my own custom logger.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes sense to take as starting point OkHttp Logger Interceptor (https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor). And then redirect all output to the file. So you'll get nice looking logs with urls, headers, content.

Answer (score 11):

In retrofit 2:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
...
HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger fileLogger = new HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger() {
    @Override
    public void log(String s) {
        writeToFile(s);
    }
}
Interceptor fileLoggerInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(fileLogger);
builder.addInterceptor(fileLoggerInterceptor);
....
```

`writeToFile` is where you actually write to the file system

For instance:

```
try {
    FileOutputStream outputStream = mContext.openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    outputStream.write(data.getBytes());
    outputStream.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This implementaion helped me a lot. thank u very much.

Comment: This answer solved me a real headache!  
  
Retorfit2/OkHttp were writing to catalina.out...

Answer (score 5):

you can add Logger to RestAdapter when building it with

```
new RestAdapter.Builder()
... other methods
.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
.setLog(new RestAdapter.Log() {
        @Override
        public void log(String message) {
           // code for storing logs in file
        }
    })
.build();
```

you should adjust loglevel to whatever level it suits you

Answer (score 1):

```
   val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor(object : HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger {
            override fun log(message: String) {
                LogUtils.d(TAG, message) //my logger which save logs into file
            }
        }
        )
        logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

        val okHttpClient: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .build()
```

It works for me.